# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in NLTK

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, nltk, list-comprehension

I have this piece of code and I would like to lemmatize a list of words based on conditions with a list comprehension, but i keep getting a 'unhasable type list' error.

Here's the code snippet:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import wordlist
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore = ['?', '!', ',', '.']


for intent in intents['intents']:
  for pattern in intent['patterns']:
    word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
    words.append(word_list)
    documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
    if intent['tag'] not in classes:
      classes.append(intent['tag'])
```

```
words  = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore]

words = sorted(set(words))
```

here the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-7887cdbfeadb> in <module>
----> 1 words  = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore]
      2 
      3 words = sorted(set(words))
      4 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py in _morphy(self, form, pos, check_exceptions)
   2030         # 0. Check the exception lists
   2031         if check_exceptions:
-> 2032             if form in exceptions:
   2033                 return filter_forms([form] + exceptions[form])
   2034 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This code didn't generate this error. Pleas post the actual code.

Comment: What is the `word` in the for loop? Is it a list instance?...Then you are trying to compare a list against a single character in `ignore`. Check that.